# Pearson correlation between age and test score

Tags: correlation

I want to know the correlation between age and test exam. I want to know if there is a linear relationship exists between the 2 variables, but the scatter plot is confusing and I can't read it. Can someone help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would think of age as the predictor, so I’d put it on the horizontal axis. Your plot may make more sense if you do that.

Comment: Have you coded the age as categorical variables? Can you share the structure of the variables?

Comment: @Mohanasundaram  hi Mohana, the age and exam test coded as scale. does this answer your question? sorry I'm new in statistics

Comment: @Dave  hi Dave , I've tried to put the age in the axis it become more confuser –

Comment: @nora Hi Nora, From the plot I could infer that, the x axis is limited by the range (0, 200) and the y axis is limited by the range (7,9). BTW, which application are you using? If possible, try extending the range of y axis (for example, (0, 60)).

Comment: @Mohanasundaram  I use SPSS , I've tried to do what u suggested, can u see picture above ? many thanks

Comment: @Mohanasundaram May I ask if u see if there is a linear relationship that exists ?

Comment: @nora I don't see any linear relationship between the age and test score. In SPSS, you can add the trendline and see that the line will be flat. Even if it shows trend, it will not be significant.

Comment: Only the first version of the scatter plot is any use, in my view. I agree with @Dave: although the correlation is the same either way age would be better on the x axis.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out significance at conventional levels. We can't be confident about the sample size given the possibility of overplotting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data the correlation that you are looking for is very weak. It is so weak that it's impossible to be sure about it from those plots: it seems that the students who are 9 did somehow better than the others, but the difference is very little.

In conclusion, your data doesn't really support the hypothesis of the existence of a correlation between age and test results.

Comment: can I ask another question, I did an eta (η) correlation between 3 games ( categorical data) and participant age, and I got .128 does this a positive correlation? thanks for your help

Comment: coefficient [eta squared](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Eta-squared) can't be negative, and .128 is actually a very little value. to assess if that association stands as a general rule, you may want to estimate its confidence intervals. If your sample is of the same size as the one you plotted above, I can already tell that that association is not significant.

Comment: I think this is a rather stronger claim than the scatter plot warrants. The issue is that with this kind of data there could be a great deal of overplotting. Naturally it does not help that the ages are rounded. A simple question remains unanswered:  what is the calculated Pearson correlation? Other displays would be better e.g. side by side histograms or dot plots. Can you post the data?

Comment: @NickCox hi Nick, I agree with you, the sample is n=36 so It might be the data is small. I've run the person correlation between age and test exam and it gives me  Pearson Correlation=   0.000406 . I assume there is no correlation here?

Comment: Yes, I think that is practically zero. The question of research interest is now why it's not a bit stronger, even given all the variables presumably at work.